# Increment Counter in For-Each Loop for RTF Template

Tags: rtf, bi-publisher

I am trying to increment **COUNTER** variable by 1 inside a for-each loop of BIP report using below code.

However, **COUNTER** variable are not incremented not matter how many loop there is. Can someone please guide me how to do this.

Also I am aware of `position()` function but it does not suffice my needs.

```
<?xdoxsllt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'COUNTER', 1)?>

<?for-each@section:SECTION1?>
    <?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'COUNTER', xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, 'COUNTER') + 1?>
<?end for-each?>

<?xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, 'COUNTER')?>
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing the closing parenthesis `)` at the end of your `set` after the 1.  Try `<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'COUNTER', xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, 'COUNTER') + 1)?>`

Answer (score 4):

You were Missing two things:
1. 'xdoxslt' in the first line was written as 'xdoxsllt'
2. A closing braces after 1 in line no.3

```
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'COUNTER', 1)?>
<?for-each@section:SECTION1?>
    <?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'COUNTER', xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, 'COUNTER') + 1)?>
<?end for-each?>
<?xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, 'COUNTER')?>
```